# Subfield Theorem Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, field-theory, proof-explanation

Lemma. Let K be a field. A subset L of K is a subfield if and only if the following
conditions are satisfied:

(a) $0 \in L$ and $1 \in L$;

(b) if $x \in L$ and $y \in L$ then $x + y \in $L and $xy \in L$;

(c) if $x \in L$ then $−x \in L$;

(d) if $x \in L$ \ {$0$} then $x^{−1} \in L$.

How do I go about proving this? I'm aware that this is a biconditional and that the proof strategy is of the form $P \rightarrow Q$ and $Q \rightarrow P$.

Why does showing L satisfy the above imply it is a field?

Thanks - greatly appreciated.

Comment: L is a subset of a field, to show L is a field, some properties are automatically satisfied, you only need to show the remaining properties.

Comment: Why do we only need to show the remaining properties??

Comment: I only tell you the purpose of this lemma, think about associativity, when you apply this lemma, you don't need to show associativity. But when you prove this lemma, of course you need to show the steps why + is associative on L. For example, since + is associative on K, then + is associative on L as $L\subset K$.

Comment: I do not follow...

Comment: LHS: L is a field, RHS: only part of field properties of L. So how can you prove from RHS to LHS? You can only use the fact that L is a subset of K and K is a field. Then prove L satisfies all the other field properties.

Comment: Check the definition of field and subfield yourself, you need to know what other field properties you have to prove for L